# Extjs 4.1 wait for stores to load in window for multiple comboboxes

Tags: extjs, combobox, load, store

I'm using ExtJS 4.1. I am trying to wait for all the the stores for comboboxes to load. I listen for the beforerender event of the window.

In this if the combobox count is not defined, then I  get all the comboboxes, save the count, load the stores and register a callback that decrements the combobox count. When the count goes to zero, it call the show method, and the window is displayed.

If the combobox count is defined, then if it is zero, I return true to allow the window to show, otherwise I return false.

However, the problem is that not all of the comboboxes show the displayValue, and show the 
valueField instead.

```
    console.log('--- onWindowBeforeRender');

if (typeof this.comboboxCount != 'undefined') {
    if (this.comboboxCount == 0) {
        console.log('returning true:');
        return true;
    }
    else {
        console.log('returning false1:');
        return false;
    }
}

var x = component.query('combobox');

console.log('x.length:');
console.log(x.length);

this.comboboxCount = x.length;

for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    var y = x[i];

    console.log('y:'+i);
    console.log(y);

    y.store.load({
        scope: this,
        callback: function(records, operation, success) {
            this.comboboxCount--;

            console.log('comboboxCount:' + this.comboboxCount);
            if (!this.comboboxCount) {
                console.log('all stores loaded.');
                this.show();
           }
        }
    });
}
console.log('returning false2');
return false;
```

Here is the code for the comboboxes:

```
                    {
                        xtype: 'combobox',
                        anchor: '100%',
                        fieldLabel: 'Region',
                        name: 'region_id',
                        displayField: 'name',
                        store: 'RegionStore',
                        valueField: 'id'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'combobox',
                        anchor: '100%',
                        fieldLabel: 'Country',
                        name: 'country_id',
                        displayField: 'name',
                        store: 'CountryStore',
                        valueField: 'id'
                    }
```

Here are the stores:

```
Ext.define('RR.store.CountryStore', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

  requires: [
  'RR.model.CountryModel'
  ],

  constructor: function(cfg) {
  var me = this;
  cfg = cfg || {};
  me.callParent([Ext.apply({
      model: 'RR.model.CountryModel',
      storeId: 'CountryStore',
      proxy: {
      type: 'ajax',
      api: {
          create: '/country/create',
          read: '/country/read',
          update: '/country/update'
      },
      reader: {
          type: 'json',
          root: 'countrys'
      }
      }
  }, cfg)]);
  }
});

Ext.define('RR.store.RegionStore', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

  requires: [
  'RR.model.RegionModel'
  ],

  constructor: function(cfg) {
  var me = this;
  cfg = cfg || {};
  me.callParent([Ext.apply({
      model: 'RR.model.RegionModel',
      storeId: 'RegionStore',
      proxy: {
      type: 'ajax',
      api: {
          create: '/region/create',
          read: '/region/read',
          update: '/region/update'
      },
      reader: {
          type: 'json',
          root: 'regions'
      }
      }
  }, cfg)]);
  }
});
```

Comment: Well it sounds your problem is about the combos so you you should post some code for them?

Comment: How and when are you setting the value of your combos?

Comment: I do not explicitly  set the value of the combos, the "name" field is id for the valueField.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue. The store for the combobox was requesting only 25 records at a time. Not all of the records were loaded. and therefore the id was not being found and the displayField's value was being set to the valueField.

Changing the server side code to ignore start/limit solved the problem.

From the store's documentation:

> If this store is buffered, this can ONLY find records which happen
>       to be cached in the page cache. This will be parts of the dataset 
>       around the currently visible zone, or recently visited zones if 
>       the pages have not yet been purged from the cache

Comment: You know you don't have to have the server ignore start and limit. I assume if there is no param start / limit the server won't include them.  If this is the case, you can instead set limitParam and startParam to undefined in the proxy store for your comboboxes.